# how to get a unknown amount of numbers and show the third biggest?

Tags: java

As the title says i have no clue how to do this ,cant make an array because don't know how many numbers are there? When the user entered the  input "0" the code need to show the third highest number.
edit:cant you list or array that is dynamic

Comment: use a collection. a list if you don't care about duplicates, or a set, if you do.

Comment: Whack it into a `TreeSet`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider is right. Create a TreeSet with a reverse Comparator and then iterate over the third element.

Comment: @vefthym no reason to reverse the comparison, just read from the other end...

Comment: @BoristheSpider agreed, but I believe iterating from first to last is easier to write, using an enhanced loop. No arguing though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you maintain array of top 3 numbers and keep sorting it...

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] largest = new int[3];

while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    int number = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    if (number == 0) {
        break;
    }
    if (number > largest[0]) {
        largest[0] = number;
    }
    Arrays.sort(largest);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(largest));
    System.out.println(largest[0]);
}
scanner.close();
System.out.println("Third largest " + largest[0]);
```

Comment: Cant use list,is there any way around that

Comment: @DavidBarishav See my new solution

Comment: I think he want the third largest number. So you should fill the `largest` array at positions `0 - 2` and sort to get the third biggest.

Comment: But i dont know how many numbers i will get,in the end it will enter the number 0

Comment: @DavidBarishav that's the point, it doesn't matter now many numbers. You just need to store 3...

Comment: He means that `inputs` is of unknown size, so it can't be stored in an array. He keeps getting numbers until the user enters the number 0.

Comment: inputs here is only to show a working example. The original question does not provide code to show where the numbers come from...

Comment: But how would you get the numbers into the array?

Comment: the numbers come from a scanner ,basically from the user

Comment: They wouldn't be in an array, I wasn't go to do the entire homework for you, but I'll update my answer with Scanner etc...

Comment: @Adam don't call `Arrays.sort`, it's unnecessarily slow. You are basically playing with Insertion Sort here. Find where the new element belongs in the array (the first element smaller than it) and insert it and shift everything long. This is significantly more efficient.

Comment: I take your point but given 1) it's driven by user input 2) it's homework, do you really think performance matters??

Comment: @Adam given it's homework, I don't think the OP would be allowed to use `Arrays.sort` anyway. But more importantly, it's important that the OP understands what is going on here and writing it explicitly achieves that goal.

Comment: I actually cant use sort,but i got the idea and will try to write without it,one more question what is exactly scanner.hasNext()

Comment: Look at the javadoc: "Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input.
     * This method may block while waiting for input to scan.
     * The scanner does not advance past any input."

Comment: @Adam you're using `Scanner` incorrectly. You need to call `nextLine` after `nextInt` otherwise the next call to `nextInt` will get `\n` which is not a valid `int` and throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `ArrayList` for this. You can initialize the list with:

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

than just add the elements with

```
l.add(value);
```

The array list automatically allocates more space for you. Hope that helps.

Comment: Cant use list,is there any way around that

Comment: How do you get the numbers? You should know how much numbers do you get.

Comment: It will keep getting the numbers and when it will finish it will enter 0

Answer (score 0):

You only need an array with three slots.  One slot hold the biggest number so far.  The next slot holds the second biggest number so far.  The third slot holds the third biggest number so far.

Read through your long list of numbers, keeping the small array updated appropriately.  There is no need to store more than three numbers, plus the current number you are examining.